# Sticky notes on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, desktop-gadget, sticky-notes

I have Sticky notes running as a widget on windows 7. I would like to do the following

- Change that front to arial narrow and BOLD. I am aware of the font change fix. How do I get the bold in there
- Increase the  sticky notes SIZE ( dimensions )  to whatever I want ( so far it will let me toggle across sizes that are far too small for all my stuff to be seen , without scrolling .

I am sure its under the hood regedit stuff  but not sure where and what . Appreciate your help there.

Answer (score 6):

In both the Sticky Notes program and the widget, these will work:

- To **INCREASE** text size: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>+<kbd>></kbd>
- To **DECREASE** text size: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>+<kbd><</kbd>
- To **BOLDEN** the text: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>
- To **ITALICIZE**: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>
- To **UNDERLINE**: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>
- To **STRIKETHROUGH**: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- To add a **BULLET LIST**: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>
- To **CAPITALISE**: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>
- To **RIGHT ALIGN**: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
- To **CENTER ALIGN**: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>
- To **LEFT ALIGN**: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>

These shortcuts should also work in most word processors - like word, pages etc...

---

To make the dimensions of the note bigger, dragging the dotted triangle at the bottom left should work, but if it doesn't, the note will automatically get bigger as you type more text, you should always be able to see all the text as long as it isn't longer 
than your screen actually is.

---

For fonts, 2 options:

Option one:

Copy and paste one letter in a font (like Times New Roman) from word (or similar) and then start editing from the pasted letter.

Option two:

1. Start > type `regedit`
2. Navigate to: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts`
3. On right pane Find "Segoe Print (TrueType)" **and** "Segoe Print Bold (TrueType)" -  double click (don't forget to change both - one by one)
4. Change the value (double click on font) to the file name of any other font that you wish to use that is already installed (eg. times.ttf)
5. Restart the computer

**MAKE SURE YOU HAVE A BACKUP BEFORE YOU DO THIS.**

**NOTE: THIS WILL STOP YOU FROM USING THE FONT YOU DELETE IN *ALL* APPLICATIONS**

More info at [Microsoft's Technet](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/a75ad434-fc85-4840-8798-f2205cc026d4/how-to-change-sticky-note-font?forum=w7itproui).

Comment: Hi Thanks . How about increasing  the size ( dimensions ) of the stickys. Dragging the lower R corner does not help

Comment: It should work by dragging the dotted triangle at the bottom right - as you said, but if not, it should automatically resize as you type, if you have more text, the note itself should get bigger - thats what happens on my computer